# How can I change Viewpager image sources (different albums)?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slideshow

I have 4 albums which each has 20 images. As default first albums images loading. I want to switch between images. I use viewpager for sliding but I can't change the source of images to other albums images.

How can I change the resouorceIDs list with the drawer item selection or anotherway?

Here is my MainActivty.java. I try to change resourceIDs to r1,r2,r3,r4,r5...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private BitmapFactory.Options options;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Integer> images;

public static int[] resourceIDs = new int[] {
        R.mipmap.p19,
        R.mipmap.p18,
        R.mipmap.p17,
        R.mipmap.p16,
        R.mipmap.p15,
        R.mipmap.p14,
        R.mipmap.p13,
        R.mipmap.p12,
        R.mipmap.p11,
        R.mipmap.p10,
        R.mipmap.p9,
        R.mipmap.p8,
        R.mipmap.p7,
        R.mipmap.p6,
        R.mipmap.p5,
        R.mipmap.p4,
        R.mipmap.p3,
        R.mipmap.p2,
        R.mipmap.p1,
        R.mipmap.p0
} ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    images = new ArrayList<>();

    //find view by id
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    setImagesData();


    // init viewpager adapter and attach
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), images);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //right to left sliding
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount() - 1);
}

private void setImagesData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < resourceIDs.length; i++) {
        images.add(resourceIDs[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the drawer code:

```
private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

    //creating fragment object
    Fragment fragment = null;

    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {
        case nav_album1:
            fragment = new Album1();
             images = new ArrayList<>();
             resourceIDs = new int[] {
                    R.mipmap.p5,
                    R.mipmap.p4,
                    R.mipmap.p3,
                    R.mipmap.p2,
                    R.mipmap.p1};


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), images);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            //setContentView(R.layout.kdaria);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_album2:
            fragment = new Album2();

            images = new ArrayList<>();
             resourceIDs = new int[] {
                    R.mipmap.r5,
                    R.mipmap.r4,
                    R.mipmap.r3,
                    R.mipmap.r2,
                    R.mipmap.r1};


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), images);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;

        case R.id.nav_album3:
            fragment = new Album3();

            images = new ArrayList<>();
             resourceIDs = new int[] {
                    R.mipmap.s5,
                    R.mipmap.s4,
                    R.mipmap.s3,
                    R.mipmap.s2,
                    R.mipmap.s1};


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), images);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            break;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "with the drawer item selection"... Your question show no drawer related code

Comment: I have a drawer  with 4 items. When i select first item i want to update arraylist to that albums images.

Comment: Okay, so where's that code that handles the drawer clicks?

Comment: You can [edit] your question with new code. Please don't post unformatted code into the comments.

Comment: I added the drawer code to question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You must use the `mipmap`/s folders to contain **only the aplication icon**. As per Google's guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is your code.

> ```
> private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) { 
>     Fragment fragment = null; 
>     switch (itemId) { 
>         case R.id.nav_album2: 
>             fragment = new Album2(); 
>             images = new ArrayList<>(); 
>             resourceIDs = new int[] { R.mipmap.r5, R.mipmap.r4, R.mipmap.r3, R.mipmap.r2, R.mipmap.r1}; 
>             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
>             break;
> ```

What are you notifying? You changed nothing about the `adapter` data.

If you want to simply show different data in the ViewPager, you need to actually update the `images` list. Then you can notify.

```
private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) { 
    images.clear(); // Always clear
    List<Integer> newImages=new ArrayList<>();

    switch (itemId) { 
        case R.id.nav_album2: 
            newImages = Arrays.asList(
                R.mipmap.r5, R.mipmap.r4, R.mipmap.r3, R.mipmap.r2, R.mipmap.r1);
            break;
        case R.id_nav_album3:
            newImages = Arrays.asList(...);
            break;
        }

    images.addAll(newImages);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // always notify
}
```

Takeaways:

1. Don't make `images = new ArrayList<>()` because your adapter no longer "sees" `images`.
2. You only need one adapter. You update the one reference to `images`, and you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` properly.
3. You don't need to repeat so much code of setting and creating adapters.

Comment: Cool. I wasn't sure what you were doing with that `fragment` variable, though. Seems to be unused.

Comment: cricket_007 when sliding page viewpager still have some images of other galleries. When I turn back they disappear. Is there a way to clear viewpager chases or current image?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you